# iPad apps never install in Retina simulator

Tags: ios, ipad, ios-simulator, retina-display, xcode4.5

I've racked my brains over this one, and I'm probably just making a stupid mistake. After switching to Xcode 4.5.1 (it may have happened at 4.5) I simply *cannot* load an app into the iPad Retina simulator. I've edited the compilation scheme to say to **always** use the Retina display for the iPad. No love. It used to be that you could change simulators on the fly and whatever one was open would be the one the project compiled for. But I can't figure out how to  do this in 4.5. Help!

Comment: Which OS version is the simulator running? Just tried on mine and if using 5.0 it seems to only launch the non-retina sim.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, after a long session of "find all of my settings files and save them, delete Xcode and all of its settings files, reinstall Xcode, re-download simulators and dockets, replace settings files, etc., etc." I found myself in the same position. No Retina simulator for me.

The problem wasn't Xcode or the project file--the ***5.0*** simulator will simply not launch in Retina mode. The ***5.1*** and ***6.0*** simulators work fine, as I discovered when I switched to them in the compilation scheme. Switch back to 5.0 and I'm stuck in normal simulator mode. The reason I've been using the 5.0 simulator was to test lowest-common-denominator iOS features. That, and there is a bug in iOS 6.0 that affects large packet transfer via IPSec that hasn't been fixed yet.

So, I still don't know what the missing Derived Data status was all about, except that it's fixed now and I assume that reinstalling the app was the fix.

Comment: Did you not see my comment? 5.0 sim will not launch in Retina, I'm assuming because there are no Retina iPads running 5.0.

Comment: I didn't see your comment until I'd left this answer. You can manually switch the 5.0 sim to Retina. You just can't launch it as part of the compile/run/debug process. You're right about there being no Retina iPads running with 5.0--hadn't thought of that.

Answer (score 5):

Something funky is going on, which seems to be not acting as expected. Try these solutions in the following order.

1. Your method is correct, you set your Simulator Display preference when editing your schemes. **Make sure** your destination for the scheme is the iPad simulator, that it's tied to the **Run** scheme, and set iPad Simulator display to Retina. Save/apply your scheme changes, try to run your app. If that doesn't work, close + re-open Xcode, check scheme settings to see if they stuck, and try again

   [image: How to change simulator display preference]

   You may want to double check if your changes stuck. Delve into your project file (by right clicking on your project file, and selecting "Show Package Contents"). Then navigate to:

   ```
   xcuserdata->username.xcuserdatad->xcschemes->ProjectName.xcscheme
   ```

   Open it up in your favourite editor, and check to see if there's a:

   ```
   simulatorIPadDisplay = "2.000000"
   ```

   ...for your required scheme
2. If none of that worked, then it may be an issue with your derived data (unlikely, but step 1 should have worked). Go to Organizer, and select the Projects tab. Then hit 'Delete...' for derived data. Do the same as before; run, close Xcode, check and re-run.

   [image: How to delete derived data within Organizer]
3. Well we really are in a pickle, that is the only method to set your preferred simulator display for a build scheme. You may need to resort to removing Xcode and re-installing, and trying the previous steps again.
4. What on earth is going on?! We've exhausted our methods, you may need to let Apple know about this issue.

Comment: Curiouser and curiouser. Your comment about Derived Data caused me to go looking and according to the Xcode Organizer, there is no Derived Data (to delete) when it clearly exists in `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData`. I tried deleting the folder manually. Xcode rebuilt the indices as I would expect, but the Derived Data entry in the Organizer remains greyed out. I trashed Xcode and downloaded a fresh version, same result. I guess the next step is to do a complete uninstall, reinstall and see what happens. I'd just hate to lose all of my custom settings...