# How to make XCode launch iPad simulator in retina mode?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator, retina-display

Even if the simulator is already running in retina mode, when I launch my app through XCode it switches back to non-retina mode. Is there a way in my app build-settings to make it require a retina iPad, or to force the simulator to run in retina mode?

Running XCode 4, Simulator 5.

Comment: possible duplicate of [iPad apps never install in Retina simulator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13158879/ipad-apps-never-install-in-retina-simulator)

Comment: Try cleaning your XCode project, and then restarting both XCode and your Simulator.

Answer (score 0):

I found the missing setting (though this question does seem to be a duplicate and could be closed):

[image]